# UITextField Showing (null)

Tags: ios, uitextfield

This was working fine and I want to say it changed after I upgraded xcode.  Basically I have an IBAction Button for the number 2 when pressed updates a UITextfield.  It works, but it is putting (null)before the 2 now for some reason.  Example:  (null)2

If I hit the clear or delete button and press 2 again it's fine.  It's just when it launches the first time.

```
-(IBAction)button2 {
display.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@2",display.text];

}
```

Any ideas?
thanks for your time,
DK

Comment: It means that either `display` or `display.text` is `nil`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the first time `display.text` is (null) because there's nothing written

to fix this in `viewDidLoad` write: `display.text = @""`

Comment: Or if display is added programatically he can write this after when it is initialized.

Comment: @rokjarc obviously can be done in various ways, the base is that at first the textfield is null ;)